How to adjust thumb size smaller than track size in SwitchCompat Android
How to adjust thumb size smaller than track size(or how to adjust the size of the Thumb) in SwitchCompat Android.

Specifically I want my SwitchCompat to look like this.
I have consulted many other questions on stackoverflow but got no result or undesirable results. How to achieve as shown in the image above

I found a way to work around this. Simply set the Thumb's stroke color to transparent to achieve that effect.
ic_track
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="@color/orange_fec017"
                        android:endColor="@color/orange_ff6200"
                        android:angle="-60" />
                    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
                    <size android:width="40dp" android:height="20dp" /> 
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#E0E0E0" />
                    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
                    <size android:width="40dp" android:height="20dp" /> 
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>

ic_thumb:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <size android:width="@dimen/dp20" android:height="@dimen/dp20"/>
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/dp4" android:color="@color/transparent"/>

</shape>

Switch
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_customize_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/ic_thumb"
    app:track="@drawable/ic_track"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/mySwitchTheme"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp15"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/label_title"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/counter_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/label_title" />

If it doesn't work, add the theme section.
<style name="mySwitchStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
</style>
<style name="mySwitchTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="switchStyle">@style/mySwitchStyle</item>
</style>

And here is the result:

If you want a smaller thumb size, just adjust the size of the thumb stroke.

To adjust the thumb size of a SwitchCompat to be smaller than the track size, you can use a custom drawable for the thumb. Here's how:

Create a Custom Drawable for the Thumb

Set Custom Dimensions for the Track

Customize the SwitchCompat in your XML LIKE:
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/customSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
    android:track="@drawable/track_drawable"
    android:thumbTextPadding="0dp"
    android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
    android:switchPadding="4dp" />





Create selector for track like "track_selector": gray_corners_rectangle when false and the orange gradient one when true:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gray_corners_rectangle">
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/orange_corners_rectangle">
    </item>
</selector>


xml for switchCompat:
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumb="@drawable/circle_white"
    android:track="@drawable/track_selector"
    android:switchMinWidth="35dp" />



